# Flask HTML site does not display .png image

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to make a site in VS Code using Flask and Python, but I'm having problems with the image in the static folder not showing up on my site. Here's what my directory looks like:

[image]

Here's a snippet from base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset="utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>{% block title %}TheAkashicLibrary.com{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p style="display:inline-block;">
            <h1 style="color: brown;"><image src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/akashiclibrarybook.png') }}">
            The Akashic Library</h1>
        </p>

    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to display akashiclibrarybook.png which is in my static folder, but here's how it looks on my server:

[image]

Here's my views.py file:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

views = Blueprint('views', __name__, template_folder="templates")

@views.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")
```

Here's my **init**.py file:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(__name__):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'i love bananas'

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint (views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint (auth, url_prefix='/')

    return app
```

Here's my main.py file:

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app(__name__)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I also get this error when clicking the link of my .png file in VS Code:
[image]

Why is it interpreting the file title this way?
I tried writing Blueprint('views', **name**, static_folder='static') and importing url_for, but nothing changed. How do I fix this?

Comment: app = Flask(__name__,static_url_path='', 
static_folder='static', template_folder='templates')

Comment: Writing app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='website/static', template_folder='website/templates') worked, thank you!!